# Link in a Label to the UserControl page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a link in a **Label** to the aspx page **UserControl** .ascx.cs.

The link text is there ( I can see it) but the error is:

```
CS0103: The name 'All' does not exist in the current context
```

Here is what I did in code.

**.ascx**

```
<asp:Label ID="All" runat="server" Text="All"></asp:Label>
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
      ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;

    string UrL = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>";
    All.Text = UrL;
  }
```

Comment: Provide complete code for .ascx. Looks like you have Templates in markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Check that on your **WebUserControl.ascx** you have in the Page directive, the attribut :

```
Inherits="yourWebApplication.WebUserControl"
```

2- Check that on your **WebUserControl.ascx.designer.cs** you have

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label All
```